# (Libre Office / Base Database) always tries to connect ODBC using iODBC, not unixODBC on Mac OSX 10.10

Tags: sql, odbc, libreoffice, unixodbc, iodbc

I am using Libre Office Version: 4.3.4.1 on my Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite.

In Base Database, I would like to connect MS-SQL server using unixODBC DSN.

But it seems the Libre Office tries to connect via iODBC, not unixODBC.
(I never installed iODBC on my Mac.)

Here is what I tried.

[Following instructions](http://www.joecjr.com/2014/07/27/install-and-use-freetds-unixodbc-and-rodbc-or-pyodbc/), I already setup unixODBC, FreeTDS using Homebrew and all the tsql/isql connection tests were fine.

After installing, I launched "Database Wizard" from Base database.
And choose 'ODBC' from "Connect to an existing database", 
I entered `s01`, my unixODBC DSN name, to "Name of the ODBC data source on your system" field. (When I clicked 'Browse' no registered data source were shown.)
And I typed my unixODBC username and checked Password required.

When I clicked 'Test Connection' button and input the password, an error occurred as below.

```
[iODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Driver could not be loaded.

SQL Status: IM002

[iODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Driver could not be loaded
```

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you stick with iODBC, the ODBC driver manager Apple has shipped as part of OS X since Jaguar (10.2).  The version Apple bundles into Yosemite (10.10) remains a bit behind, at 3.52.6, so I would also recommend you update to [3.52.10](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads#Mac_OS_X).

iODBC and UnixODBC are built to be API equivalent, so you should just need to ensure that your drivers and DSNs are properly configured in the iODBC locations, optimally via `iODBC Administrator.app` (`/Applications/iODBC/`).  System DSNs are recommended for most purposes.

```
/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini         # System DSNs
/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini     # System drivers
~/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini        # User DSNs
~/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini    # User drivers
```